# Dynamically swapping *Local project* WPF Themes (Styles) at runtime

Tags: wpf, prism

I am created a new project, where I will need to change the themes dynamically.

I have seen plenty of posts about this where you do this via the App.xml..

eg
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

```
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary
  {
   Source = new Uri(Themes/MyTheme.xaml, UriKind.Relative)
  });
```

This works fine, however, since this is going to be a large project, and I was going to have each View in it's own projects (ie following the Prism structure), I wanted each project to have i't own local theme .xaml files, and swap these (ie rather than having everything in the main application ("Shell") project.

My sample projects can be found at

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30760237/ThemesSwap.zip

In here I have a helper that will change the themes at runtime (MainView2.ThemeHelper))

If you run the project as is, when you click the button, we can see the old theme (pink background) remove, but the new one (black background) does not load.

The only way I can get it to work is adding the following "link" into the App.xaml file (it is commented out in the attached)

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 <ResourceDictionary Source="/MainView2;component/Themes/DarkTheme.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

My question is, is there a way to NOT have to link these themes in the main project, and have them totally encaplusated in each of the view projects? I can't understand why we need to reference these in the main project?

Thanks in advance for any help

regards, Peter

Comment: Haven't looked at your code, but am curious as to why you'd want module-level themes. That seems like a UI disaster to me. I think it makes perfect sense for the shell to dictate the theme, and the modules to inherit it and override only the bits they need to.

Comment: Perhaps a good point Kent, will have a bit more of a think about that.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Someone has told me the answer to this so thought would share it..

"You need to use the pack URI for a resource file that is compiled into a referenced assembly:"

ie have the "/MainView2;component" prefix...

Source = new Uri(="/MainView2;component/Themes/MyTheme.xaml, UriKind.Relative)